# Hierarchical data - Recursive CTE plus PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I have the following self-referencing hierarchical table:

```
SubCodes

ID int PK
ParentID int
Code varchar(25)
FKID int
```

e.g.

```
ID    FKID      ParentID    Code
1     25        NULL        1100
2     NULL      1           1110
3     NULL      2           1111
```

I would like to write a query such that I get back

```
FKID    Answer                IDOfLowestNode
25      '1100,1110,1111'      3
```

I suspect I need a CTE AND a PIVOT - but it's just twisting my brain as to how to do it - any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @SubCodes table (ID int,ParentID int,Code varchar(25),FKID int)

insert into @SubCodes (ID,FKID,ParentID,Code)
values
(1,     25,        NULL,        1100),
(2,     NULL,      1,           1110),
(3,     NULL,      2,           1111)

;with cte as
(
  select ID RootID,ID,ParentID,Code, CAST(Code as varchar(500)) answer
  from @SubCodes
  where ParentID is null
  union all
  select cte.RootID,sc.ID,sc.ParentID,sc.Code, CAST(cte.answer+','+sc.Code as varchar(500))
  from @SubCodes sc
        join cte on cte.ID=sc.ParentID
)
select c.answer, r.id LowestNode
from cte c
     join (select RootID, MAX(id) id FROM cte GROUP BY RootID) r ON c.ID=r.id
```

Comment: brilliant! I shall read, learn and absorb  - and hope that the next time I have such a query that I can bend my brain round the recursive CTE on my own.

Comment: @kpollock Actually, it is not so hard as you can think. Although, 7 years ago I was afraid of it myself :) So, good luck. To understand recursion you need to understand recursion :)

Comment: :-) oh recursion I am fine with - just not used to expressing it declaratively, only procedurally.